# I need to change the output of a query so that instead of it coming back as the abbreviation 'em' it says 'employee'. Tsql

Tags: t-sql

I have the correct result coming back. I just need to convert 6 abbreviations in that result to their correct names. There are 20k names assigned to 1 of 6 abbreviated names.

I tried aliasing but that seems to only work for table names.

I tried doing a case statement but that didn't work.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Stating "I tried doing a case statement but that didn't work." doesn't help us help you since we can't see your code and T-SQL doesn't have a `case` _statement_, only a [`case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) expression. Did you try something like `case AbbreviatedColumn when 'em' then 'employee' when 'vo' then 'vogon' else AbbreviatedColumn + '?' end as CorrectName`?

Comment: You forgot to show us your attempt that didn't work.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. HABO gave me enough to sort out my mistake.

Comment: A better solution that is more maintainable and extensible would involve using a translation table that maps abbreviations to replacement words or phrases.  Adding an abbreviation would be a data change instead of a code change.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more details (like some sample input and output), but if you have data like EM100, and you want to make it EMPLOYEE 100, then you could use an expression such as:

```
CASE WHEN ColumnName like 'EM%' THEN 'EMPLOYEE ' + SUBSTRING (ColumnName,3,100)
     WHEN ColumnName like 'RN%' THEN 'REGNURSE' + SUBSTRING (ColumnName,3,100)
     else ColumnName END
```

But providing more details will help provide a more specific answer.